# Is there an existing XSLT extension that allows inspecting/unzipping files?

Tags: xslt, zip

Before I write my own java extension, I'm looking for a xslt feature or xslt extension to allow inspecting content of a zip file, and unzip the content.

I tried looking in the xslt 2.0 spec, did not mention any unzipping. I tried googling, and got an experimental expath.org/mod/zip, but compiler says cannot find the matching function "entries()".

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an extension in Java that does inspection and unzipping of zip files.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an existing XSLT extension that allows inspecting/unzipping
>   files?

**Yes -- one that I am aware of is the [Zip module of EXPath](http://expath.org/modules/zip/)**.

Comment: If you contact Florent Georges about this I suspect he will be motivated to move it forward to a more formal status.

Comment: Note also: if you know what you are looking for, Saxon will make an individual file within a ZIP archive accessible using the Sun-defined jar: URL scheme.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, ya, that one I have actually tried (as noted in the OP) but it did not compile for me for some reason.

Comment: @Jason: AS noted by Michael Kay, it is a good idea to contact Florent Georges for anything related to EXPath.